# phpMyAdmin loginbox missing on Ubuntu Nginx

Tags: mysql, nginx, cloud, phpmyadmin

Hi I am using cloud hosting from digitalocean and running nginx , mysql server . everything is running good with phpmyadmin ...

i install phpmyadmin as well but getting some problem that's can't see login options ... you can check phpmyadmin here ( https://demo.wpthemeocean.com/phpmyadmin/ )

And here is my php info ( https://wpthemeocean.com/ )

Hope some one help me to overcome the issue ..

thanks

Comment: I get a number of JavaScript errors that I posted here: https://imgur.com/a/mHzaTav

Comment: May i know ! how to fixed the error , it's default view of phpmy admin

Comment: You probably sent no `X-XSS-Protection` header or you sent it twice.

Comment: issue fixed ! the problem was X-XSS-Protection !